# OS X Application Firewall dialog vanishes without user input

Tags: cocoa, sockets, firewall

I am creating a BSD socket with `socket` and then attempting to `listen` to it. The call to `listen` causes an Application Firewall dialog to appear when the firewall is active, but it disappears too quickly for a user to interact with it. I have found that pretty much any delay to the call to `listen`, such as adding breakpoints in the debugger or a call to `sleep`, after the call to `socket` will cause the dialog to appear and remain long enough for the user to interact with it. If the dialog vanishes before the user can choose anything, the firewall denies all subsequent incoming requests to that app.

Does anyone know what causes the dialog to vanish, and if there is a more appropriate way to prevent it other than calling `sleep`?

If anyone wants to try and reproduce this, I am attaching code that causes this behavior below. If `waitForUserInput` is true, the dialog will appear and remain until the socket is closed. If it is not true, the dialog vanishes in a split second. If you add a breakpoint on the line that tests `waitForUserInput`, it will show the dialog for 5 seconds even if that variable is `NO`. In all these cases, the call to `listen` does not return an error. I am using OS X 10.7.4 and Xcode 4.2 .

```
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <netdb.h>

static void firewallDialog(BOOL waitForUserInput){
    struct addrinfo *res, *p, host;

    memset(&host, 0, sizeof host);
    host.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // no preference for IP4/6
    host.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP
    host.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // local IP address

    if(-1 != (getaddrinfo(NULL,"1234",&host,&res))){
        int sock = -1;

        for(p = res; p != NULL; sock = -1, p = p->ai_next) {
            // make a socket
            if(-1 == (sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol))){
                continue;
            }

            if(p->ai_family == PF_INET6){
                ((struct sockaddr_in6*)p->ai_addr)->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
            }
            if(-1 == bind(sock, p->ai_family == PF_INET ? INADDR_ANY : p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)){
                close(sock);
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(res);

        if(-1 != sock){
            if(waitForUserInput){ sleep(1); }

            if(-1 == listen(sock, 20)){
                close(sock);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Call to listen was successful");
                sleep(5);
                close(sock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```